# How to find duplicates with a query in MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I need to find inside my table on my MySQL database duplicated values with the same name but with different sport.
Here is an example of data:

```
John Smith    Athletics
Edward Green  Athletics
Edward Green  Fencing
Jim Brown     Rugby
Jim Brown     Rowing
Jim Brown     Sailing
Stan Smith    Football
Stan Smith    Football
```

Well, I'd like to make a query which give me this result:

```
Edward Green  Athletics
Edward Green  Fencing
Jim Brown     Rugby
Jim Brown     Rowing
Jim Brown     Sailing
```

As I said, only that values with the same name but different sport, in order to find namesakes.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option using `exists`:

```
select *
from yourtable t
where exists (
    select 1
    from yourtable t2
    where t.name = t2.name and t.sport != t2.sport
    )
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e74f/1)

Answer (score 1):

The inner select gets all `name`s having more than one distinct `sport`. To also get the sports for those names, you have to join against the same table

```
select t1.*
from your_table t1
join
(
    select name
    from your_table
    group by name
    having count(distinct sport) > 1
) t2 on t1.name = t2.name
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT name, sport FROM My_table) AS Temporary_table_name
GROUP BY name
HAVING ( COUNT(name) > 1 )
```

With command

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, sport
```

you exclude duplicated combinations of name and sport (namely "Stan Smith - Football") and after it you can look for repeated names with peace of mind (because you know they won't refer to the same sport)

Answer (score -1):

Another posbility with no suquery will be to use Having with a COUNT :

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourtable t
GROUP BY name
HAVING ( COUNT(name) > 1 )
```